# Could not load MSBuildSdkResolver

Tags: c#, .net-core

Downloaded zip of https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017

Loaded it up and get:

Project2015To2017.Tests.csproj : error  : 
The SDK resolver assembly …
 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver\Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I have the .Net Cross Platform module selected in the VS Installer.

MSBuildSdkResolver.dll is not on my file system.

Do I need to specifically download the dotnet core SDK from: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1 ?